# Is libunwind implementation of abi in libcxxabi?

Tags: llvm, libc++, libunwind

I was trying to build `libcxx`/`libcxxabi`/`libunwind` when I realized that I didn't actually understand what role they play.

I checked [libcxxabi spci](https://libcxxabi.llvm.org/spec.html), and found that it defines API used in C++ exception. But I can't find any document about `libunwind`,  and one blog([New libunwind implementation in libc++abi](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/10/new-libunwind-implementation-in-libcabi.html)) I found by google says that `libunwind` is the implementation of `libcxxabi`.

So, is `libunwind` really like that, implements ABI in `libcxxabi`, if so, why we have `libcxxabi`?

Answer (score 0):

I built `libunwind` myself and checked the symbols in `libunwind` by using `nm` and got these:

```
nm: libunwind.cpp.o: File format not recognized
nm: Unwind-EHABI.cpp.o: File format not recognized
nm: UnwindLevel1.c.o: File format not recognized
nm: UnwindLevel1-gcc-ext.c.o: File format not recognized
nm: Unwind-sjlj.c.o: File format not recognized

UnwindRegistersRestore.S.o:
0000000000000000 T _ZN9libunwind16Registers_x86_646jumptoEv

UnwindRegistersSave.S.o:
0000000000000000 T unw_getcontext
```

That seems to imply that `libunwind` just implements the unwind functions, nothing else.